# Passing 2 structures as parameters to pthread in C

Tags: c, linux, struct, pthreads, arguments

Can I pass two structures as parameters to a pthread in a C program. I need to do something like this:

```
void *funtion1(void *pass_arg, void *pass_arg1)
{
    struct thread_arg *con = pass_arg;
    struct thread_arg1 *con = pass_arg1;
    //necessary code
}
int main()
{
pthread_t threaad;
//necessary code
while(1)
{
    th1 = pthread_create(&threaad, NULL, function1, (void *)&pass_arg, (void*)&pass_arg);
//necessary codes
}
pthread_exit(NULL);
return 1;
}
```

I mean is there any way I can pass two structures into the same function while using pthread? Operating Platform: Linux.

Comment: Bury a pointer to the second structure in the first?

Comment: How can I bury a pointer to the second structure in the first?

Comment: How did you defined the *current* fields in `struct thread_arg`? Is adding one more (`struct thread_arg1 *p1;`) out of the realm of possibilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, because the functions in libpthread accept only one user data argument. But that should be enough, shouldn't it?

```
struct user_struct {
    void *p1, *p2;
} arg = { &arg1, &arg2 };

pthread_create(&tid, NULL, threadfunc, &arg);
```

Also, don't cast pointers to `void *`, it's superfluous, dangerous and decreases readability.

Comment: I am fairly weak in pointers. Can you tell me how to nest structures inside another structure by using pointer and how to call them?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT I just showed that in the sample. Did you read it?

Answer (score 1):

Define a new struct type which contains the two original types as members. Call it something meaningful like `thread_args`.

Comment: You mean to create a struct by nesting the two structures that I need to pass as arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by nesting the two structures into a single structure like this:

```
struct s1
{
    //variables
};

struct s2
{
    //variables
}

struct s3
{
    struct s1 ss1;
    struct s2 ss2;
}
void *funtion1(void *pass_arg)
{
    struct s3 *con = pass_arg;
    //necessary code
}
int main()
{
    //code
    th1 = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, function1, (void *)&pass_arg);
}
```

Comment: This looks curiously close to the solution that Oli has proposed. Tradition on SO would be that you (1) acknowledge this, (2) upvote his answer, (3) accept that answer.